# Traer último valor autonumérico con Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Necesito traer el último dato auto-numérico de esta consulta Linq, pero no sé dónde colocar el `FirstOrDefault()`

```
private void cargarGrillaPersona()
{
    var query = from us in contexto.USUARIO
                orderby us.ID_HOJA descending
                select new 
                {
                    No_Documento = us.DOCUMENTO, 
                    Nombres = us.NOMBRES, 
                    Apellidos = us.APELLIDOS, 
                    Correo = us.CORREO, 
                    Fecha_Registro = us.FECHA_REGISTRO};

    gvUsuario.DataSource = query.ToList();
    gvUsuario.DataBind();
}
```

Cuando encierro entre comillas desde el `from` hasta el final, aparece un error, algo de `tuplas.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from us in contexto.USUARIO
             orderby us.ID_HOJA descending
             select new 
             {
                No_Documento = us.DOCUMENTO, 
                Nombres = us.NOMBRES, 
                Apellidos = us.APELLIDOS, 
                Correo = us.CORREO, 
                Fecha_Registro = us.FECHA_REGISTRO
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Si es que te da error, podrias mandar cuales datos

Comment: Hola HCK1, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu respuesta me parece la correcta, sin embargo, solo considero que deberías mencionar que el `FirstOrDefault()` se debe poner al final.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que cambiar el **ToList()** por **FirstOrDefault()**

```
ModeloUSuario Usuario = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Aparece el error "El origen de datos no es un tipo válido. Deber ser IListSource, IEnumerable o IDataSource."

Comment: asignalo directo al gvUsuario

Comment: No se a que te refieres cuando dices asignarlo directamente?

Comment: Es que a como lo tienes en tu ejemplo _gvUsuario.DataSource = query.ToList();_ estás asignando una lista al DataSource.
El objeto que estás consultando debe de ser de los mismo elemntos a los que tienes en tu tabla. tu objeto gvUsuario es igual a tu tabla USUARIO?

Comment: Los datos corresponden solo a una tabla, ya había probado como lo indicas esta ultima vez y aparece el siguiente error, CS1061: 'AnonymousType#1' no contiene una definición de 'ToList' ni se encontró ningún método de extensión 'ToList' que acepte un primer argumento de tipo 'AnonymousType#1' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: Es por la diferencia de datos, el FirstOrDefault(); te traera los datos para que los pases a un objeto. como dvUsuarios es una tabla, por eso no te lo reconoce.